# How to fix the duplication of my arrays from the form inputs

Tags: angular

I created an angular Hotel booking application that stores the reservations inside an array, but every time i add a new reservation the last one gets updated and replaced with the new one.

I tried following a CRUD Artist app tutorial on youtube, it has similar functionalities

```js
// this method calculates the array variables before they are pushed

getCost(reserve: reservations) {
  this.person.map((b) => {
    if (b.id) {
      if (b.id === reserve.id) {
        reserve.id++;
      }
      b.name = reserve.name;
      b.lastname = reserve.lastname;
      b.email = reserve.email;
      b.phone = reserve.phone;

      b.category = reserve.category;
      b.checkin = reserve.checkin;
      b.days = reserve.days;
      b.people = reserve.people;

      if ((!b.days) || (!b.people)) {
          alert('Something went wrong in assigning the day or people');

        } else if (b.category === 'Single') {
          reserve.cost = 399.00 * b.days * b.people;
        }  else if (b.category === 'Double') {
          reserve.cost = 599.00 * b.days * b.people;
        } else if (b.category === 'Twin') {
          reserve.cost = 799.00 * b.days * b.people;
        } else if (b.category === 'Deluxe') {
          reserve.cost = 1999.00 * b.days * b.people;
        }

      b.cardnumber = reserve.cardnumber;
      b.cardholder = reserve.cardholder;
      b.expiary = reserve.expiary;

      if ((b.cardnumber === undefined) || (!b.cardnumber)) {
        reserve.payment = 'Unverified';
      } else {
        reserve.payment = 'Verified';
      }

    } else {
      alert('Id should not be empty');

    }

  });

}

// this method calls the method above then pushes the data into the array
  addPerson(v: any) {
    this.getCost(v);
    this.person.push(v);
  }
```

I expect each new array to contain new data and the old ones to stay the same with their data, but im getting duplicate data

Comment: Quite unclear. What strikes me is that the callback passed to map() doesn't return anything, and that you're ignoring the value returned by the call to map(). So you're seriously abusing map(). map() is used to transform an array into another array, by transforming each of the element of the original array into something else. It shouldn't have side effects. Your code has plenty of side effects: it modifies the elements of the original array, and also modifies reserve (and does it for every element of the person array).

Comment: So that's the reason for the duplication thank you Evert.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace .map() call with .forEach()

Comment: What i understand about the forEach() is that it reads all all the indexes in the array, the displays them, thing is i don't want to just display the array i want to also manipulate the values in the index then push them in my array.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
No, Array#forEach iterates through array elements and executes callback for each element.

Comment: I will look into it. Thank you.